# Let $T(N)$ denote the number of arrangements of the integers 1,2,...,N into a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_i>a_{2i}$ and $a_i>a_{2i+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

For a positive integer $N$, let $T(N)$ denote the number of arrangements of the integers $1,2,\dots,N$ into a sequence $ a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N$ such that $a_i>a_{2i}$ for all $1\leq i \leq 2i \leq N $ and $a_i>a_{2i+1}$, for all i, $1 \leq i <2i+1 \leq N$.
For example T(3) is 2, since the possible arrangements are 321 and 312

(a) find T(7)

(b) If K is largest non negative integer so that $2^k$ divides $T(2^n-1)$

(c)Find the largest non-negative integer K so that $2^k$ divides $T(2^n+1)$.

---

Now , I was only able to do $1^{st}$ part and I will write my thoughts and ideas below

---

Now for N=7
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@.@.a_5\\
@.@.@VVV\\
@.a_1 @<<<a_2 @<<<a_4\\
@.@AAA \\
@.a_3 @<<< a_6\\
@.@VVV\\
@.a_7
\end{CD}

Now, we can see than in this inequality tree,
**$a_1$** lies on top, so **$a_1=7$**

So now we are left with 2 sub trees of $a_2$ and $a_3$

Lets choose 3 integer form {1,2,3,4,5,6} for a sub tree.
It can be done by $^6C_3$
and the largest among these integer will be $a_2$(or $  a_3)$ and then other left 2 integer will have 2 permutations.

Now for the other subtree, we are left with 3 integer and largest of them will be $a_3$(or $a_2$)
and other two integer will have 2 permutations

so now $\begin{align}T(7)&=^6C_3*2*2\\
&=20*2*2\\
&=80\\
\end{align}$

---

For other question, I tried the same method but was getting problem in understanding

*Any help will be grateful to me* and **Thank You In Advance!!!!**

Comment: Presumably. $n$ and $N$ are the same? If so, pick one.

Comment: If $2^k\leq n< 2^{k+1}$ then you get a recursion: $$T(n)=\binom{n-1}{2^k-1}T(2^k-1)T(n-2^k),$$ or something like that.

Comment: No they are not same @ThomasAndrews

Comment: For starters, you should work out $T(15)$, then $T(31)$, then $T(63)$, until you can guess a general pattern for $T(2^n-1)$, and prove it. This will help determining the largest $k$ so $2^k$ divides $T(2^n-1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @MikeEarnest

Comment: If $n$ and $N$ are not the same, shouldn’t it be $1\leq 2i\leq n,$ not $1\leq 2i\leq N?$

Comment: And if $n$ and $N$ are not the same, isn’t the function $T$ a function of the two variables, $N$ and $n?$

Comment: Boi N is just  a notation in question T(N) means arrengements and of 1,2,3….N

Comment: And T($2^n-1$) = arrangements of 1,2,3,4…..$2^n-1$ @ThomasAndrews

Comment: But then why does $a_1,\dots,a_n$ end in $n$ and not $N?$

Comment: oh sorry Now I have corrected it @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@thomas-andrews is almost correct in his recurrence. Consider a number $a$ written in binary.  Given prefix $a'$ of this binary number, $a$ must lie in the subtree under $a'$.  So divide numbers $1<a<=m$ into two sets beginning with $10$ and $11$. Let the size of these sets be $S(m)$ and $m-1-S(m)$.  We then have the recurrence
\begin{equation}
T(m) = {m-1 \choose S(m)} \cdot T(S(m)) \cdot T(m-1-S(m)) \,.
\end{equation}
Now, calculating $S(m)$ is another question.  Fortunately, we don't have to. In the two particular cases you mentioned, it is easy to see that $S(2^n-1) = 2^{n-1}-1$ and $S(2^n+1) = 2^{n-1} + 1$.
So for b) we have
\begin{equation}
T(2^n-1) = {2^n-2 \choose 2^{n-1} -1} \cdot T(2^{n-1}-1)^2
\end{equation}
and for c) we have
\begin{equation}
T(2^n+1) = {2^n \choose 2^{n-1} +1} \cdot T(2^{n-1}+1) \cdot T(2^{n-1}-1) \,.
\end{equation}
Now to count the powers of 2 in each of those values is a relatively easy recurrence.

Comment: We can also use Legendre's formula to count powers of $2$ after getting the recursion. In fact, this problem is INMO $2022$ Problem $3$. Discussion on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2795422p24604457